# como seleciono somente os dados de uma celula de dataframe? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

estou tentando selecionar somente o valor de uma celula em uma planilha excel
mas o retorno vem informações a mais. ex: nome da coluna, index, etc
code:

```
#pandas
#pandas
import pyperclip as pyper
import pandas as pd

tabela = pd.read_excel("teste.xlsx")

#SELECIONANDO COLUNAS ESPECIFICAS
dado1 = tabela.loc[[1, 5, 7], ["CÓD REDUZIDO","PREÇO"]]

dado2 = dado1.loc[1]

dado2.to_string()

pyper.copy(dado2.to_string())

print (dado2)
```

saida:

```
CÓD REDUZIDO    416485
PREÇO            26.99
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

saida do clipboard:

```
CÓD REDUZIDO    416485
PREÇO            26.99
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 1):

Considere o seguinte `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

dados = {
    'X': [1, 3, 5],
    'Y': [3, 33, 333],
    'Z': [10, 20, 30],
}
indice = list('abc')

df = pd.DataFrame(dados, index=indice)
print(df)

# output:
#    X    Y   Z
# a  1    3  10
# b  3   33  20
# c  5  333  30
```

Se quisermos pegar um elemento usando a *nomenclatura do índice e colunas*, usamos o [método `.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas.DataFrame.at):

```
# quero o elemento que está: 
# na linha de índice 'a'
# e na coluna de nome 'Z'
print(df.at['a', 'Z'])

# output:
# 10
```

Se quisermos pegar um elemento usando *índice da linha e coluna de interesse*, usamos o [método `.iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html#pandas.DataFrame.iat):

```
# quero o elemento que está: 
# na 3ª linha (índice 2)
# na 1ª coluna (índice 0)
print(df.iat[2, 0])

# output:
# 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode obter um valor específico utilizando o método `.iloc` da biblioteca pandas.

**Exemplo**:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'coluna_1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'coluna_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

print(df)

# Saída
#    coluna_1 coluna_2
# 0         1        a
# 1         2        b
# 2         3        c
# 3         4        d
```

O método [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) faz uma indexação baseada na posição em valores inteiros para seleções por posição.

ou seja,

podemos passar na estrutura do método `.iloc[posição linha, posição coluna]` valores inteiros para retornar o valor desejado. Vemos isso na sequencia abaixo do código.

```py
valor = df.iloc[1, 1]
print(valor)

# Resultado: b
```

**Referência:**

1. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Answer (score -1):

Para pegar apenas o valor de uma célula, basta utilizar o método [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - coloco um exemplo simples abaixo.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[0, 1], [1, 0]], columns = ["a", "b"])
df.head()

#   a b
# 0 0 1
# 1 1 0

df.loc[0, "b"] # Out: 1
```

Pode ser interessante procurar sobre o método [`.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) também.

Comment: não force a aceitação da resposta. Caso o usuário agradeça a resposta e não a aceite uma ou outra resposta, então [oriente o autor da pergunta a fazer a aceitação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/707/coment%c3%a1rios-enlatados-para-situa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-comuns/6972#6972) se passarem 24h da publicação da(s) resposta(s) e não houver aceitação então faça uma  orientação genérica abaixo da pergunta.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).